# How to add lower third text graphics to a video using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to add text to my video. Something like this:

[image]

So far I've tried this command, **but the text doesn't wrap**:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf \
"format=yuv444p, \
drawbox=y=ih/PHI:color=black@0.4:width=iw:height=48:t=fill, \
drawtext=fontfile=OpenSans-Regular.ttf:text='Title of this    Video':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:x=(w-tw)/2:y=(h/PHI)+th, \
format=yuv420p" \
-c:v libx264 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [subtitles](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) filter and it will wrap automatically. You can use the simple but limited SRT format, or the more complex ASS format. Aegisub is useful if you want to format the subtitles, or see the `force_style` option in the subtitles filter.

[image]

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "subtitles=title.srt,format=yuv420p" -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Comment: I'd also like(the caption) to be in the bottom or on the top of the video as it is in the picture in the question

Comment: @archie Yes, that is possible. Refer to *Alignment* or `\an` or `\pos` tags. http://docs.aegisub.org/3.2/ASS_Tags/

Comment: How is the title.srt supposed to be like? I'm getting "Conversion failed" message

Comment: @archie [Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubRip). But you should be using ASS since it supports the `\an` and `\pos` tags.

Answer (score 0):

The `drawtext` filter *doesn't support automatic wrapping.*

So, if you want to display your text in *n* lines, you have to use the `drawtext` filter *n* times, *with different values* for parameters `text`, `y` (and maybe `x`, too) for every line.

Comment: Would it be responsive that way?